# Why the user input still go through the loop while I'm entering "YES" to the RobotQ1 input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, while-loop

Basically, once the user has decide to entered "YES" as per the RobotQ1 variable, I want the code to start again, however, it goes through the 2nd user input which RobotQ2.

```
restart = "Yes".lower()
while restart == "YES".lower():
         print(" In order to obtain the harmonized code of your item answer all the following questions")
         print()
         print("Q1 : Does your car have 4 wheel drive")
         RobotQ1 = input("YES / NO ?:")
         if RobotQ1 == "YES".lower():
            print("Here is the HS code:...")
            restart = input("Do you want to use the application? (Yes / No): ")         
         if restart =="NO".lower():
            print("bye")
            break
         elif RobotQ1 == "NO".lower():
            print("Q2 : Does your Robot have 7 axes ?")
         RobotQ2 = input("YES / NO ?:")   
         if RobotQ2 == "YES".lower():
            print("Here is the HS code:....")
            restart = input("Do you want to use the application? (Yes / No): ")
         if restart =="NO".lower():
            print("bye")
            break
```

Comment: Don't you also want to lowercase `RobotQ1`: `if RobotQ1.lower() == "yes":`. Because otherwise, `"YES" != "yes"`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to start over your loop without breaking out, in this case:

Add `continue`

> The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning
>   of the current loop. When encountered, the loop starts next iteration
>   without executing the remaining statements in the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically You want is

> if RobotQ1 is Yes==> Give HS Code and ask for Restart
>
> if Robot Q1 is No ==> Ask 7 Axes (if Yes) ==> give Hs Code ==> Ask For Restat

I Think Here is Nice One

```
restart = "Yes".lower()

while restart == "Yes".lower():
    print(" In order to obtain the harmonized code of your item answer all the following questions")
    print()
    print("Q1 : Does your car have 4 wheel drive")
    RobotQ1 = input("Yes/No ?:")

    if RobotQ1.lower() == "Yes".lower():
        print("Here is the HS Code ...")
    else:
        print("Q2 : Does your Robot have 7 axes ?")
        RobotQ2 = input("Yes/No")
        if RobotQ2.lower() == "Yes".lower():
            print("Here is Hs Code")

    restart = input("Do you want to use the application? (Yes / No): ")
    restart.lower()

    if restart == "No".lower():
        print("bye")
        break
```